# Capturing field values in custom content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

When I have this in my template:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'front_page_slider'));
foreach($nodes as $slider): ?>
<?php //print $slider->title; ?>
<?php $heading2 = $slider->field_heading_2; var_dump($heading2);?>
```

It prints:

```
array(1) { ["und"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["value"]=>
  string(14) "Item Heading 2"
  ["format"]=> NULL ["safe_value"]=> string(14) "Item Heading 2"
} } }
```

What is the better way to do this? I am just trying to loop through nodes in the content type "front_page_slider" and print the values for each field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it as follows:

```
print $slider->field_heading_2['und'][0]['safe_value'];
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.